# Firebase.h file not found in App.delegate.m

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

Good day all,

Hope that you guys are doing fine. I have this problem right here that my `Firebase.h file not found` inside my `Appdelegate.m`. I attach some screenshots a long with this post for my `Headers Path` inside my Xcode and for the `folding structure` that is inside my project. I appreciate any help

[image: Headers Path]

[image]

Comment: Are you using react-native-firebase library? Check if you are running project from .xcworkspace or .xcodeproj? you have to switch to .xcworkspace.

Comment: I'm running on .xcodeworkspace

Comment: refer to the link once. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/198